# express server does not find file to download

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am facing a strange issue, with my express server: I want  download a file  inside a folder that is created at run-time; this is my code:

```
var folder = id.toString()
          var file = [projectRoot,"/app/temp/",folder, "/registrazioni.zip"].join("")
          console.log('file',file)
          res.download(file,'registrazioni.zip')
```

I know that all the variables  are defined, but res.download raise an error:

```
 { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/giuseppe/projects/csgSAW/app/temp/undefined/registrazioni.zip']
```

errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/home/projects/csgSAW/app/temp/undefined/registrazioni.zip',
  expose: false,
  statusCode: 404,
  status: 404 }

where I should see the folder, got undefined, but the consolo.log just before res.download is correct, so I am very puzzled, do notr know what is wrong.
I am working with node 4.2.6 and express ^4.14.0, thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is `id`? Your `folder` is `undefined`, as you can see in the path (`.../temp/undefined/registrazioni.zip`).

Comment: Id= new Date().getTime(), anyway I know for sure that id is not undefined in console.log is ok

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `id` variable is undefined.

> where I should see the folder, got undefined, but the consolo.log just before res.download is correct

There is no way the string is correct in the `console.log` line, but not below it. If that really is the case, something must have changed the string to replace the id with 'undefined'.

Comment: I created a pastebin of the outpu thttp://pastebin.com/z76Tpabr  in the console.log id is correct, but I have no idea what  have changed the string